# How to perform an "internal" redirect in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I understand how to redirect users using redirect() method, but this method returns a 302 code and the browser must make a second HTTP request. Is it possible to internally forward the request to a different controller and action?

I'm doing this check in middleware so my handle function looks like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if (auth()->user->age <= 20) { //example
        //internally forward the user to a different controller@action
    }

    return $next($request);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `call` method as:

```
app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName@funName')
```

Or

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName')->funName();
```

So your middleware will look as:

```
if (auth()->user->age <= 20) {
   return app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName@action');
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get the error "Call to a member function setCookie() on null". 
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 136
at FatalErrorException->__construct('message' => '???', 'code' => '???', 'severity' => '???', 'filename' => '???', 'lineno' => '???', 'traceOffset' => '???', 'traceArgs' => '???', 'trace' => '???') in HandleExceptions.php line 133
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError('error' => '???', 'traceOffset' => '???') in HandleExceptions.php line 118
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0

Answer (score -3):

You can use `redirect()` helper method like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if (auth()->user->age <= 20) { //example
      return redirect()->route('some_route_name');
  }

  return $next($request);
}
```

Inside your routes file, the route should be defined as:

```
Route::get('users/age/', 'ExampleController@method_name')->name('some_route_name');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And this will not return a 302 or 301?

Comment: No I don't think so, its given on laravel docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#defining-middleware

Comment: I tested this and this does in fact return a 302 redirect which I wanted to avoid